# data sharing while using API

Tags: apex, api

The API's accessing salesforce will be able to get the complete data from salesforce (sure, we can set API user's profile to restrict this access).

How can **with Sharing and without Sharing** benefit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the with sharing or without sharing keywords on a class to specify whether or not to enforce sharing rules.The with sharing keyword allows you to specify that the sharing rules for the current user be taken into account for a class

1.The sharing setting of the class where the method is defined is applied, not of the class where the method is called.

Ex:

```
Public with sharing  class ctrl1{
                //this class enforce to apply sharing rules
                 public void testMethod1{
                 }
      }
```

---

```
Public without sharing  class ctrl2{
            //sharing rules are by passed in this class
            public void testMethod2(){
                                ctrl1   ct=new ctrl1();
                                   ct.testMethod1();
                                //this method excutes by enforcing sharing rules.
            }
 }
```

2.Both inner classes and outer classes can be declared as with sharing.The sharing setting applies to all code contained in the class including initialization code, constructors, and methods
.
3.Inner classes do not inherit the sharing setting from their container class.

4.Classes inherit this setting from a parent class when one class extends or implements another.

5.If with or without sharing are not mentioned on class then default is " WITHOUT SHARING"